# What would happen in a single slit diffraction experiment if the slit ends are made of photo sensitive material?

Tags: diffraction, photoelectric-effect

In a single slit diffraction experiment if the slit ends are made of a photosensitive material,
And if a light wave falls on the ends of the slit, will it get diffracted or will it lead to ejection of photoelectron? 
Diffraction shows the wave nature of light and photoelectric effect shows particle nature of light.
In the situation stated above will it show wave nature or particle nature?

Answer (score 2):

If done with regular light sources it will show both, provided that the frequency is above the threshold. However if you send in photons one at a time, you’ll either see the photoelectric effect, or a detection on the screen. But not both simultaneously. Keep in mind that the detection on the screen is still a blip localised at some point. But over time, from the buildup of detections on the screen the diffraction pattern will emerge.

This is equivalent to saying that the photon will either be detected at the obstruction (slit) or will pass through the slit (detection at the screen). You might be interested in [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/533368/201709).

Comment: Is there any way to determine the probability of each of them occurring Using dimensions of the slits? If slit dimension is more then diffraction is less likely to occur. But can you give a probability value for it?

Comment: @Bhargav the probability hitting material or passing through is infinitesimal, since one models these things with an incoming plane wave (extends to infinity). IRL, you need a beam profile, and we don't have that.